# How to get public-facing name from Google cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am looking for a way to get the public-facing name from Google cloud function?

Any idea if doable?

If you can also give me the Google site that list the other information about my project, it will be nice also. I could not find anything so far. :-( I will keep looking in the mean time.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by public-facing name? What information are you expecting to see? Do you have an example of how it looks said information?

Comment: @Emmanuel, if you go to your Firebase project settings and in 'General' tab you will see a section called 'Your Project - Public settings' and then a field called "Public-facing". I want to get that information.

Comment: I see, what would be the purpose of that information? I'm asking because this is an specific information for the Firebase Apps and Cloud Functions reside on the GCP Cloud Console, and probably what you want to achieve is doable through other ways

Comment: @Emmanuel, from a cloud function, I want to send an email and the subject will use the name. I don't want to hard code that value and instead use the one already inside the projet settings.

Comment: I didn't catch what you want to do. Do you want a public name of your function, with your own DNS name? And you want so variable to use in your function to customize things instead of hardcoding the values right?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, did you understand the information I want to get (see previous answer that I gave to Emmanuel). I just need a way to get that name, in javascript cloud function. If possible, of course. By the way, that name can be edited from Firebase console.

Comment: Sorry I don't know very well firebase and I didn't catch this. AFAIK, you can't. Cloud Function are isolated of Firebase configuration. However, it's possible that somewhere in Firebase Cloud Function you can populate Environment Variables (in any cases, it's possible with Cloud Functions). And you can get these values in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there's no way to retrieve the %APP_NAME% from inside the Cloud Functions since those are isolated from Firebase and reside on the GCP side. However as a workaround to avoid hardcoding you can send [Environment Configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env) variables through the next command:

```
firebase functions:config:set app.name="APP_NAME"
```

Then inside your Cloud Function you can retrieve your configuration variables by using:

```
functions.config().app.name
```

Comment: I fully agree. Just want to leave a comment that _some_ Firebase info is available in the Functions environment: `process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG` seems to contain `databaseURL`, `storageBucket` and `projectId` [according to docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#automatically_populated_environment_variables)